# Why didn't EE.SE use uint16_t for its question index?

Tags: discussion

Every question is the database adds a *huge* amount of data:

- The question
- The answer(s)
- All the comments
- Rev history for question
- Rev history for answer(s)
- Associated tags
- Linked questions
- etc etc

All this ASCII has got to take up an amazing amount of space!  **Megabytes, perhaps!**  Why not limit the question index to 16 bits just to keep the database manageable?

Comment: (don't take this seriously; see the answer!)

Answer (score 2):

**It's because so much awesomeness couldn't fit in a mere two bytes!**

[image]

(I tried to catch it at 65,536, but I missed)

**Happy Third Byte, everybody!**